# 'El proveedor 'Microsofot.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' no está registrado en el equipo local.'. en C# VS Community

Tags: c#, visual-studio

¿Cuál es la cadena de conexión para acceder a archivos Excel 2016 y replicarlos en un DataGridView?, actualmente estoy intentando acceder a archivos excel por medio de un botón con un openfiledialog. Al intentar acceder a el, me da error: '**El proveedor 'Microsofot.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' no está registrado en el equipo local**.'

1. le instalé desde https://www.microsoft.com/es-es/download/details.aspx?id=13255 la versión x32
   después intenté con la x64 y el error persiste.

Cambie el método de darle la cadena de conexión desde el código pero aun así persiste el error.

2. También cambié la plataforma de destino en propiedades del proyecto, probé con x64, x86 x32 y ninguna opción me evita ese error.

¿Alguna idea porque se está dando persistentemente este error?

La primera cadena de conexión que probé fué: `string connection = string.Format("Provider = Microsofot.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = {0}; Extended Properties = 'Excel 12.0;'", filename);`

después al ver que seguía sin funcionar probé con un metodo privado.

````
//Este metodo lo implemente después del string connection que se encuentra comentado
private string ExcelConnection(string fileName)
         {
             return @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" +
                    @"Data Source=" + fileName + ";" +
                    @"Extended Properties=" + Convert.ToChar(34).ToString() +
                    @"Excel 8.0" + Convert.ToChar(34).ToString() + ";";
         }

//Código completo
namespace Excel_A_Datagrid
{
 public partial class Form1 : Form
 {
     public Form1()
     {
         InitializeComponent();
     }

     private string ExcelConnection(string fileName)
     {
         return @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" +
                @"Data Source=" + fileName + ";" +
                @"Extended Properties=" + Convert.ToChar(34).ToString() +
                @"Excel 8.0" + Convert.ToChar(34).ToString() + ";";
     }

     DataView DataImport(string filename)
     {
         var excelconnection = ExcelConnection(filename);
         //string connection = string.Format("Provider = Microsofot.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = {0}; Extended Properties = 'Excel 12.0;'", filename);
         OleDbConnection connector = new OleDbConnection(excelconnection);
         connector.Open();
         OleDbCommand query = new OleDbCommand("select * from [Hoja1$]", connector);
         OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter
         {
             SelectCommand = query
         };
         DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
         adapter.Fill(dataset);
         connector.Close();
         return dataset.Tables[0].DefaultView;
     }

     private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {

     }

     private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         OpenFileDialog openfiledialog = new OpenFileDialog
         {
             Filter = "Excel | *.xls;*xlsx;*.csv;",
             Title = "Seleccionar Archivo"
         };

         if (openfiledialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
         {
             DGVDataImport.DataSource = DataImport(openfiledialog.FileName);
         }
     }
 }
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

Hola a todos los que lleguen hasta este post, investigando un poco más, encontré esta serie de soluciones, donde me sirvió mucho la publicada por Bernhard.

Ojalá a alguien que llegue por el mismo error, le sirva también esta solución.

Saludos!

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6649363/microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).